# android studio расположение элементов не соответствует

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Здравствуйте! У меня не соответствует элементы экрана, то есть в предпросмотре показывается одно расположение, а на устройстве или на эмуляторе другое расположение. Как можно это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Предпросмотр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На эмуляторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XML-код:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/korzina"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/korzina"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/korzina"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton2" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/telpek"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/koyukizil"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/ertegiler"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Видимо, на эмуляторе и при предпросмотре указаны разные разрешения экрана устройств

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы увидеть, как ваше приложение будет выглядеть при определенном разрешении экрана и при определенной ориентации экрана, можно нажать на вот эти замечательные кнопочки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И чуть левее - ориентация экрана.
Когда вы нажмете на нее, сможете выбрать любое для вас подходящее устройство и даже добавить свое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]